# Python script page is showing blank?

Tags: python

I have completely unknown in Python. I have no idea about this script. Now i am just starting Python code in my server.

I am getting Blank page of my code

Please check my code Below:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html"
print "Hello, Python!"
```

Comment: What version? How are you running it? What server?

Comment: It's probably printing to console and very quickly closing the window before you ever see it. Are you running it in IDLE or just double-clicking the `.py` file?

Comment: There should be another newline between the headers (`Content-type:`) and the body. Also, why are you telling the client you're serving an HTML document and then proceed to serve plain text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the HTTP header needs to be an blank line and you can use HTML instead of plain text.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/html\n"
<html>
<body>
<p>Hello, Python!</p>
</body>
</html>
```